# WiFi Network Adapter Missing on windows 11

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, drivers, windows-11

I recently moved and used to connect my PC to the internet via Ethernet. I now need to connect it via WiFi.
My PC has an Intel AX200 WiFi chipset on board its motherboard, ROG X570-I. In the UEFI, WiFi Controller is set to Enabled. However when I go into Windows 11, the WiFi adapter is missing from the control panel under network connections, change adapter settings; and is also missing from the device manager. On my Mac I downloaded the latest driver from Intel, put it on a USB and then successfully installed on the PC. Rebooted, still no adapter. In device manager, the adapter doesn't appear even with view Hidden on. I also tried resetting network settings, and executing a bunch of nets reset commands (IPV4 and TCP).

Any tips?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you installed the correct driver? It may not be the most up-to-date but this one is directly from the (motherboard's) manufacturer: https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-x570-i-gaming-model/helpdesk_download/

Comment: @ChanganAuto - The author should install the driver directly from [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/189347/intel-wifi-6-ax200-gig/downloads.html). Intel released 22.200.0.6 recently.  However, I suspect the device is in a non-operational status, so the driver won't matter.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree 100%. My previous comment was to rule out some wrong driver having been installed by mistake. That said, I suspected a non-operational device immediately.

Comment: Definitely correctly installed the driver straight from intel.

Comment: Is it perhaps disabled in bios? Section 3.6.4 in your manual

Comment: It is not double checker that and even toggled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities: hardware issue or OS/drivers.
To test, boot from USB with another OS, e.g., [Ubuntu Live](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) -- there's no need to install anything to the PC, just run from USB. All recent versions of Ubuntu i.e.,with [kernel 5.1 or later](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149116/intel-wifi-support-for-ax200-cyclone-peak)) should be able to find the Intel AX200 WiFi modem and connect with it, *if* the hardware is functional.

- If the modem works under alternate OS, then concentrate on fixing Windows.

  - See [MiniTools](https://www.minitool.com/news/intel-wifi-6-ax200-not-working.html) about this issue, though you've tried most of their suggested remedies.
  - Run [SFC and DISM](https://winaero.com/how-to-repair-windows-11-with-sfc-and-dism) to let Windows try to find and repair any issues.
  - If SFC and DISM can't fix the issue, try [reinstalling Windows from ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11/), keeping your data. It's a good idea to *first* make a disk image, though, lest data be lost.
- If the alternate OS *cannot* find the modem, concentrate on hardware.

  - Check if the WiFi modem is disconnected (e.g., a  loose connector). Reseat all connectors going to that board.
  - If that still didn't fix it, replace the modem. Either buy a new card (e.g., US$21 [at Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZVYKRW9)), or buy an external [USB WiFi adapter](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=usb%20wifi%20adapter).

Comment: I question if the adapter is even functional.  The device was connected to the internet, priror to the need to use the Intel WiFi adapter, so Windows should have installed the driver.  This suggests the device was and currently in a non-operational status.

Comment: Thanks I actually dual-boot linux so will try this and see. The WiFi chip is embedded on the board so I'd be surprised if it's damaged. Will follow-up soon.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't see the WiFi/Bluetooth card despite it being embedded in the processor. Guess that narrows it down to hardware or BIOS thank you!

Comment: @donkey, my choice would be a USB WiFi adapter. If the PC is not close to the router, look at those with external antenna, otherwise, the tiniest dongle will do, compatible with the router protocols. BTW, if at the limit of the router range, I find a short USB extension cable allows the adapter to be moved and oriented for best reception.

Comment: Do you have a way of verifying that it is not a BIOS issue vs Hardware?

Comment: No, but you should be able to access your PC's BIOS and see if there's any setting for WiFi.